# Errors in validating multi-level taxonomy

Tags: content-hub, sitecore-cli, taxonomy

I created a multi-level taxonomy **SampleTaxonomy** in Content Hub with hierarchy below:

[image: SampleTaxonomy Hierarchy]

I was pulling the serialized entities using ch-cli with `ch-cli serialization pull entity -d SampleTaxonomy`.

Then I validate it using `ch-cli serialization validate ent -v`, but I got errors:

```
[Error] Relation 'SampleTaxonomyToSelf' in entity 'Social Media' does not included 'Online' entity.

[Error] Relation 'SampleTaxonomyToSelf' in entity 'Out of home' does not included 'Offline' entity.
```

Does anyone have encountered the same error or know what causes this problem?

Thank you so much!